# VS2017 - Add intellisense to field in class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

How can I add intellisense to a class field in visual studio 2017 (javascript)?

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx), the `<field>` documentation should do the trick. But, I'm not getting intellisense on all available methods and fields from `WebGLRenderingContext`.

```
class myClass {

    constructor(canvasId) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById( canvasId );
        /// <field name='this.gl' type='WebGLRenderingContext'>Rendering engine</field>
        this.gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl" );
    }

    x() {
        //No intellisense
        this.gl.enable( this.gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    }

}
```

If I pass the WebGLRenderingContext to a documented constructor. I do get intellisense on the object.

```
/**
 *  Constructor
 * @param {WebGLRenderingContext} gl
 */
constructor(gl) {
    this.gl = gl;
}
```

---

As @param, the intellisense does it's job (Fields like "ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES" available).
[image: Working]

Here it doesn't provide me with intellisense
[image: Not working]

Same if using "this.gl"
[image]

Note: I know I made a mistake on getting the "webgl2" context into "WebGlRenderContext". Trying to get "webgl" working here, not "webgl2". But this shouldn't affect the intellisense.

Comment: I just tried it with and without the "this." and I am getting intellisense. What I am not getting is WebGLContext specific stuff. If you aren't getting any intellisense then your problem is something else. If you are getting something to popup then you might just need a type defintion: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webgl2/index.d.ts https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: @MikeCheel, thanks. I added some screenshots to further show the behaviour. It's not related to missing types.

Comment: @Reinard, please check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx, the document that you shared describes to define the ‘Quick Info’. Refer to your description, I am not sure did you means the ‘Quick Info’ or the ‘List Members’. Following this example to create the comments for a JavaScript field, I compared it in the VS 2015 and VS 2017 and found the ‘Quick Info’ works fine in the VS 2015 as we defined, but there is no effect in VS 2017, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgyXfzmcD8SZeg24s and I will try to report this issue to the VS Product team.